# Any resource explaining how to get a volume charge density from a surface charge density?

Tags: electrostatics, resource-recommendations, charge, classical-electrodynamics

Where (book, lecture notes) could one find 
a clear explanation (better if examples are provided) 
about how to find the volume charge density in a point 
given the surface charge density there?

Comment: I beg your pardon if I haven't been clear. I meant: if I have a charge in a point, i need to multiply it by a 3D delta function to obtain the volume density in that point. The request was how to find the volume density in a point when the surface density is provided. Thanks

Comment: Tip: Consider to reformulate question purely as a physics question without an explicit resource request. All questions are implicitly resource requests. Explicit res. recom. qs are restricted on Phys.SE.